# Zero indent for list items

Tags: html, css, text, html-lists, text-indent

My code is structured like this:

```
<article style="font-size:16px;text-indent:40px;line-height:1.5em;">
<ul>
  <li><a title="Egypt" href="#egypt" style="text-indent:0px;padding-left: -25cm;">Egypt</a></li>
</ul>
</article>
```

and yes, it is terrible that the [css](/questions/tagged/css) has to lie upon [html](/questions/tagged/html), but  let's not worry about that *now*.

This will make Egypt get the `text-indent` property of the `<article>`. However, I would like this not to happen. I would like Egypt, the list item, to have 0 text indentation!

How to do it?

Check the [js-fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gsamaras/ocrc4mbd/2/).

Comment: you have a typo tho, `"text-indent:0pxpadding-left: -25cm;"` you are missing a `;`

Comment: You are right @dippas, corrected!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the `text-indent: 0px` to the `li` instead of the `a` like in the below snippet.

The [`text-indent` property applies only to block containers](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#indentation-prop). `li` is a block container whereas the `a`  is not and hence setting it on `a` has no effect.

Also, this property is an inherited property and that is the reason why the `li` gets 40px as value from `article`. You'd notice this if you inspect the `li` and have a look at the "Computed" styles section.

```html
<article style="font-size:16px;text-indent:40px;line-height:1.5em;">
  <p>
    Goal of this page is to laconically detail where I, <strong>Georgios Samaras</strong> have travelled, since I am asked again and again and usually I forgot some places.
  </p>
  <p>
    I will list (in random order) were I have been to and say some more about the non-Greek places I have been after 2012. It's also good to write down the memories... :)
    <ul>
      <li style="text-indent: 0px;"><a title="Egypt" href="#egypt">Egypt</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</article>
```

Answer (score 2):

Removing `style="(...)"` from HTML and adding this, perhaps that's something that would help:

```
ul {
    list-style-position: inside;
    padding-left:0;
}
```

That's it, only these lines.

Comment: Yeah sure this will work, but I was seeking something like Harry's answer, thanks though! +1 for the thinking.

Comment: Well, I'm glad you have found the answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

the issue is resolved, remove style from article and apply it to p

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x0djb490/)

```
<article>
<p style="font-size:16px;text-indent:40px;line-height:1.5em;">Goal of this page is to laconically detail where I, <strong>Georgios Samaras</strong> have travelled, since I am asked again and again and usually I forgot some places.
</p>
<p>
I will list (in random order) were I have been to and say some more about the non-Greek places I have been after 2012. It's also good to write down the memories... :)
<ul>
  <li><a title="Egypt" href="#egypt">Egypt</a></li>
</ul>
</article>
```

Comment: add text-intend 0px to your li, updated fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/x0djb490/1/